# How to add a Sql Table to a Pyqt main window

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt4

I have a table which I need to add to grid in my main window. I am using python, sqlite3 and pyqt.

My Problem is that I am getting a type error

> QGridLayout.addWidget(QWidget, int, int, int, int, Qt.Alignment alignment=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QSqlTableModel'

I think this means that the addWidget is incorrect and I'm not sure what it should be? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Code is below:

```
def CreateStockDBWindow(self):
    # Create Table
    self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    self.createConnection()
    model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
    self.initializeModel(model)

    # Create Widgets
    self.AddButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Add Stock",self)
    self.RemoveButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Remove Stock",self)
    self.MoreButton = QtGui.QPushButton("More Details",self)

    # Create Layouts
    self.VLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

    # top bar

        # Create Widgets for Top Bar
    CompanyNameLabel = QtGui.QLabel("<font size='72'><b>"+"Phoenix Trading"+"</b></font>",self)
    searchLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Search:",self)
    searchLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit("",self)
    searchButton = QtGui.QCommandLinkButton("Search",self)

        # Create Graphics view
    logo = QtGui.QPixmap("logo.jpg")
    self.myScene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
    self.myScene.addPixmap(logo)
    self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.myScene)

        # layouts for top bar
    self.TopBarLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.RHSTopBarLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.RHSVLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.TopBarLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView,0,0)
    self.TopBarLayout.addWidget(CompanyNameLabel,0,1)

    self.RHSVLayout.addWidget(searchLabel,0,0)
    self.RHSVLayout.addWidget(searchLineEdit,0,1)
    self.RHSTopBarLayout.addWidget(searchButton,1,0)
    self.RHSTopBarLayout.addLayout(self.RHSVLayout,0,0)
    self.TopBarLayout.addLayout(self.RHSTopBarLayout,0,2)

    # Assemble

    self.VLayout.addWidget(self.AddButton)
    self.VLayout.addWidget(self.RemoveButton)
    self.VLayout.addWidget(self.MoreButton)

    self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.TopBarLayout,0,0,1,5)
    self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.VLayout,4,1)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(model,4,5)
    app.exec    

    return self.mainLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

A table model is not a graphical control, it is the interface between such a control and its data.

You probably want to put your table model inside a `QTableView`.

Comment: I have now done that but it will still not work it just won't load and there is no error given either. i know it has run the whole code as its covered in print statements now. any ideas?